# Does the following relation holds for infinite sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Hey i am only wondering if it is possible that the equation below holds:

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i(b_i - c_i) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} (a_ib_i - a_ic_i) =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ib_i - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ic_i
$$

Thanks!

Comment: You appear to have a typo: I think that you mean $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i(b_i-c_i)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(a_ib_i-a_ic_i)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ib_i-\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ic_i\;.$$ Yes, provided that the three series all converge.

Comment: It was a typo yes. I fixed it.

Comment: No, you haven't. $a(b-c)=ab-ac$ and not $ab-bc$.

Comment: Should still be $a_ic_i$ not $b_ic_i$.

Comment: I did fix that thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of a series is: $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_1+\ldots+a_n).$$

The answer to your question follows from the fact that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(b_n-c_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n b_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n c_n,$$ whenever all the limits have a finite value.

Comment: @GitGud: Finite in the sense that the actual limit of the series is finite. Not the index set.

Comment: A small misunderstanding on my part. Sorry.

Comment: @GitGud: You should have left the comment, it was a good remark that made the answer slightly better understood. But I suppose a small edit would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

It holds when 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i b_i$$ 
and $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i c_i $$ 
ar both unconditional convergent.

Or $$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i (b_i - c_i)$$ is unconditional convergent.

This is in the finite dimensional the case when they are absolute convergent, that means when 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty |a_i b_i|$$ is convergent.

Comment: Do you really need absolute convergence?

Comment: Do you have an example for when this fails for a conditionally convergent series?

Comment: Interesting. I thought that $0=0$.

Comment: but $\infty -\infty$ is not zero, it is indeterminate

Comment: But then $\sum a_ib_i=\infty$. This is not about conditional convergence anymore. It's just not a convergent series.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7977/discussion-between-dominic-michaelis-and-asaf-karagila)

Comment: I have no intentions using the chat system.

Comment: $$0=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n(1-1)=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n-\frac{(-1)^n}n=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n-\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n=0$$

Comment: @Asaf oh right sry take a_i = 1/n and b_n = 1,0,1,0,1,0,1, ... and c_n = 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,... yeah sry my fault

Comment: Okay. I see your point now. But it is enough to require that all three sums are evaluated to a finite number, rather than two of them are unconditionally convergent.

Comment: normally at such a stuff you need unconditional convergence, would be surprising for me if this one is different, let me think of a counter example